# How can i call inner functions in controller from outside function?while working on typeahead using angularjs getting Typeerror:

Tags: angularjs

*while calling the inner functions in **Ctrl()** function from templateResolver() ,In TemplateResolver im calling like this ---->**md-search-text-change="ctrl.searchTextChange(ctrl.searchText)"**  suggest me why i'm getting error or how to call that inner function from **templateresolver()***

Please go through Code :

```
 angular
        .module('app.components')
        .directive('dirInput', dirInput);

    function dirInput() {
        return {
            restrict: "E",
            scope: {
                inputConfig: '<',
                model: '=ngModel'
            },
            require: '^InputBar',
            template: templateResolver(),
             controller: ctrl
        };

// For context
  function ctrl($timeout,$scope, $q, $log) {   
            var self = this;
            self.simulateQuery = false;
            self.isDisabled    = false;

            // list of `state` value/display objects
            self.states        = loadAll();
            self.querySearch   = querySearch;
            self.selectedItemChange = selectedItemChange;
            self.searchTextChange   = searchTextChange;
            self.newState = newState;

            function newState(state) {
              alert("Sorry! You'll need to create a Constitution for " + state + " first!");
            }
```

```
        // ******************************
        // Internal methods
        // ******************************
            function querySearch (query) {
              var results = query ? self.states.filter( createFilterFor(query) ) : self.states,
                  deferred;
              if (self.simulateQuery) {
                deferred = $q.defer();
                $timeout(function () { deferred.resolve( results ); }, Math.random() * 1000, false);
                return deferred.promise;
              } else {
                return results;
              }
            }

            function searchTextChange(text) {
                alert("text  "+text)
              $log.info('Text changed to ' + text);
            }

            function selectedItemChange(item) {
              $log.info('Item changed to ' + JSON.stringify(item));
            }

            function loadAll() 
            { var allStates = 'Alabama, Alaska, Arizona, Arkansas, California, Colorado, Connecticut, Delaware,\
                      Florida, Georgia, Hawaii, Idaho, Illinois, Indiana, Iowa, Kansas, Kentucky, Louisiana,\
                      Maine, Maryland, Massachusetts, Michigan, Minnesota, Mississippi, Missouri, Montana,\
                      Nebraska, Nevada, New Hampshire, New Jersey, New Mexico, New York, North Carolina,\
                      North Dakota, Ohio, Oklahoma, Oregon, Pennsylvania, Rhode Island, South Carolina,\
                      South Dakota, Tennessee, Texas, Utah, Vermont, Virginia, Washington, West Virginia,\
                      Wisconsin, Wyoming';

              return allStates.split(/, +/g).map( function (state) {

                return {
                  value: state.toLowerCase(),
                  display: state
                };
              });
            }

            /**
             * Create filter function for a query string
             */
            function createFilterFor(query) {
              var lowercaseQuery = query.toLowerCase();

              return function filterFn(state) {
                return (state.value.indexOf(lowercaseQuery) === 0);
              };

            }

        }
```

```
function templateResolver() {

            var templateString =
                    ' <md-input-container class="md-accent">\n' +
                    ' <label>{{ inputConfig.label }}</label>\n' +
                    ' <input ng-if="inputConfig.type === \'text\'"  name="{{inputConfig.id}}"  ng-model="$parent.model" ng-blur="onBlur($event)" ng-required="{{inputConfig.required}}">\n' +
                    ' <md-datepicker ng-if="inputConfig.type === \'date\'" ng-model="$parent.model" md-hide-icons="calendar" ng-required="{{inputConfig.required}}"></md-datepicker>\n' +
                    ' <md-autocomplete ng-if="inputConfig.type === \'auto-complete\'" name="{{inputConfig.id}}"  ng-required="{{inputConfig.required}}" ng-disabled="ctrl.isDisabled" md-no-cache="ctrl.noCache" md-selected-item="ctrl.selectedItem" md-search-text-change="ctrl.searchTextChange(ctrl.searchText)" md-search-text="ctrl.searchText" md-selected-item-change="ctrl.selectedItemChange(item)" md-items="item in ctrl.querySearch(ctrl.searchText)" md-item-text="item.display" md-min-length="0"  ><md-item-template> <span md-highlight-text="ctrl.searchText" md-highlight-flags="^i">{{item.display}}</span></md-item-template></md-autocomplete> \n'+
                    ' </md-input-container>';

            return templateString;
        } 
}
```

Comment: Hi Ramakrishna, this question is far from clear. Would you mind rephrasing it? https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Tell us what the exact wording of the error message is, and which line of code is producing it.

Comment: while searching text from this function  md-search-text-change="ctrl.searchTextChange(ctrl.searchText)",  getting  TypeError: "items is undefined"